# pypdf Merging multiple pdf files into one pdf

Tags: python, pypdf

If I have 1000+ pdf files need to be merged into one pdf,

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

writer = PdfWriter()

for i in range(1000):
    filepath = f"my/pdfs/{i}.pdf"
    reader = PdfReader(open(filepath, "rb"))
    for page in reader.pages:
        writer.add_page(page)

with open("document-output.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer.write(fh)
```

Execute the above code，when `reader = PdfReader(open(filepath, "rb"))`,

An error message：
`IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:`

I think this is a bug, If not, What should I do？

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I recently came across this exact same problem, so I dug into PyPDF2 to see what's going on, and how to resolve it.

*Note: I am assuming that `filename` is a well-formed file path string.  Assume the same for all of my code*

**The Short Answer**

Use the `PdfFileMerger()` class instead of the `PdfFileWriter()` class.  I've tried to provide the following to as closely resemble your content as I could:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

[...]

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in filenames:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))

merger.write("document-output.pdf")
```

**The Long Answer**

The way you're using `PdfFileReader` and `PdfFileWriter` is keeping each file open, and eventually causing Python to generate IOError 24.  To be more specific, when you add a page to the `PdfFileWriter`, you are adding references to the page in the open `PdfFileReader` (hence the noted IO Error if you close the file).  Python detects the file to still be referenced and doesn't do any garbage collection / automatic file closing despite re-using the file handle.  They remain open until `PdfFileWriter` no longer needs access to them, which is at `output.write(outputStream)` in your code.

To solve this, create copies in memory of the content, and allow the file to be closed.  I noticed in my adventures through the PyPDF2 code that the `PdfFileMerger()` class already has this functionality, so instead of re-inventing the wheel, I opted to use it instead.  I learned, though, that my initial look at `PdfFileMerger` wasn't close enough, and that it only created copies *in certain conditions*.

My initial attempts looked like the following, and were resulting in the same IO Problems:

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in filenames:
    merger.append(filename)

merger.write(output_file_path)
```

Looking at the PyPDF2 source code, we see that `append()` requires `fileobj` to be passed, and then uses the `merge()` function, passing in it's last page as the new files position. `merge()` does the following with `fileobj` (before opening it with `PdfFileReader(fileobj)`:

```
    if type(fileobj) in (str, unicode):
        fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
        my_file = True
    elif type(fileobj) == file:
        fileobj.seek(0)
        filecontent = fileobj.read()
        fileobj = StringIO(filecontent)
        my_file = True
    elif type(fileobj) == PdfFileReader:
        orig_tell = fileobj.stream.tell()   
        fileobj.stream.seek(0)
        filecontent = StringIO(fileobj.stream.read())
        fileobj.stream.seek(orig_tell)
        fileobj = filecontent
        my_file = True
```

We can see that the `append()` option does accept a string, and when doing so, assumes it's a file path and creates a file object at that location.  The end result is the exact same thing we're trying to avoid.  A `PdfFileReader()` object holding open a file until the file is eventually written!

However, if we either make a file object of the file path string *or* a `PdfFileReader`<sup>*(see Edit 2)*</sup> object of the path string *before* it gets passed into `append()`, it will automatically create a copy for us as a `StringIO` object, allowing Python to close the file.

I would recommend the simpler `merger.append(file(filename, 'rb'))`, as others have reported that a `PdfFileReader` object may stay open in memory, even after calling `writer.close()`.

Hope this helped!

**EDIT:** I assumed you were using `PyPDF2`, not `PyPDF`.  If you aren't, I highly recommend switching, as PyPDF is no longer maintained with the author giving his official blessings to Phaseit in developing PyPDF2.

If for some reason you cannot swap to PyPDF2 (licensing, system restrictions, etc.) than `PdfFileMerger` won't be available to you.  In that situation you can re-use the code from PyPDF2's `merge` function (provided above) to create a copy of the file as a `StringIO` object, and use that in your code in place of the file object.

**EDIT 2:** Previous recommendation of using `merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))` changed based on comments *(Thanks @Agostino)*.

Comment: I'll be honest; I haven't read the long answer. Short answer was great though.

Comment: I noticed I couldn't delete some of the files appended creating an intermediate `PdfFileReader` object with the call `writer.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))`. They remain locked even after calling `writer.close()`. The simpler call `merger.append(file(filename, 'rb'))` does not seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this run into memory problem if the files are too big?

Comment: @Nishant As with any objects you're creating in memory, yes.  Realistically, if you're getting into the gigabytes for a single PDF file, there's likely a better solution.

Comment: @Rejected Alright thanks, its worth knowing that. A small utility function that choses named temporary file vs memory is a good solution I have seen on this.

Comment: @Nishant I doubt that would solve the problem, seeing as how the whole issue comes from a hard limit Python places on the number of open files you can have at the same time.  Furthermore, PyPDF will still need to open the new "merged" file even if you're doing this incrementally with files from the HDD.  Unless you're using another tool to reduce the PDF file size (stripping duplicate fonts, reducing image quality, etc.), you'll still see about the same memory footprint.

Comment: Oh yes good point, something to think. This does circumvent the too many files open error which actually I faced in production once.

Comment: This works but consumes a LOT of memory when working on a lot of files. I'm currently merging 2500 PDFs into one. Each PDF has 4 pages. The end result is a 10,000 page PDF. ...and my server just crashed. haha, too much memory.

Comment: @Rejected I believe for Python 3, instead of `file` in `merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))`, you'll need to use `open`.  Like `merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename, 'rb')))`.

Comment: This was exactly my question and with 'open' it works. Nice to see that this comment is 17 hours old, although the original post was 7 years old.

Comment: I wish the PyPDF documentation bothered to describe the `PdfMerger` constructor parameters. What is `classpypdf.PdfMerger(strict: bool = False, fileobj: Union[Path, str, IO] = '')` supposed to mean? `Union`?

Answer (score 3):

The pdfrw package reads each file all in one go, so will not suffer from the problem of too many open files.  [Here](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/cat.py) is an example concatenation script.

The relevant part -- assumes `inputs` is a list of input filenames, and `outfn` is an output file name:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter

writer = PdfWriter()
for inpfn in inputs:
    writer.addpages(PdfReader(inpfn).pages)
writer.write(outfn)
```

Disclaimer:  I am the primary pdfrw author.

Answer (score 3):

I have written this code to help with the answer:-

```
import sys
import os
import PyPDF2

merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

#get PDFs files and path

path = sys.argv[1]
pdfs = sys.argv[2:]
os.chdir(path)


#iterate among the documents
for pdf in pdfs:
    try:
        #if doc exist then merge
        if os.path.exists(pdf):
            input = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(pdf,'rb'))
            merger.append((input))
        else:
            print(f"problem with file {pdf}")

    except:
            print("cant merge !! sorry")
    else:
            print(f" {pdf} Merged !!! ")

merger.write("Merged_doc.pdf")
```

In this, I have used PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger and PyPDF2.PdfFileReader, instead of explicitly converting the file name to file object

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are only allowed to have a certain number of files open at any given time. There are ways to change this (http://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrlimit), but I don't think you need this.

What you could try is closing the files in the for loop:

```
input = PdfFileReader()
output = PdfFileWriter()
for file in filenames:
   f = open(file, 'rb')
   input = PdfFileReader(f)
   # Some code
   f.close()
```

Comment: if use f.close(), exec output.write(outputStream), Prompt IO error.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe just what it says, you are opening to many files.
You may explicitly use `f=file(filename) ... f.close()` in the loop, or use the `with` statement. So that each opened file is properly closed.