# How to combine multiples PDFs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I want to make an script that read all the `pdf` files in directory, copy the second page of each one and write it in one output pdf (with all the seconds pages).
I have already wrote a code but it give me a pdf with blank pages. And that is really strange because I have another code which take the second page of each pdf and make a new pdf for each second page, and that code works. I think my problem may be related with the `addPage()`.
I am using [PyPDF2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2) library to use the pdf files.

```
import pathlib
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

files_list = [file for file in pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.iterdir() if (file.is_file() and not str(file).endswith(".py"))]
total = len(files_list)    
writer = PdfFileWriter()    
for file in files_list:
    with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
        reader = PdfFileReader(infile)
        reader.decrypt("")
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(1))            
with open('Output.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)    
print('Done.')
```

Comment: why arent you using the code that does what you want then? because it does not combine the pages?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, that code doesn't combine, it just make a copy of the old pdf with only the second page, but it doesn't combine then into **one** pdf.

Comment: added an example from other answer here (modified) to my answer. credits to other answer down below.

Comment: Not a strict duplicate - but this special case is anwered by a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795091/how-to-append-pdf-pages-using-pypdf2 -answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PdfFileMerger.append](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger.append) - it allows you to merges pages from multiple pdfs into one result file.

```
append(fileobj, bookmark=None, pages=None, import_bookmarks=True)
```

> Identical to the merge() method, but assumes you want to concatenate all pages onto the end of the file instead of specifying a position.
>
> ```
> Parameters:   
> fileobj               A File Object or an object that supports the standard read 
>                       and seek methods similar to a File Object. Could also be a 
>                       string representing a path to a PDF file.
> bookmark (str)        Optionally, you may specify a bookmark to be applied at the 
>                       beginning of the included file by supplying the text of 
>                       the bookmark.
> pages                 can be a Page Range or a (start, stop[, step]) tuple to merge
>                       only the specified range of pages from the source document into 
>                      the output document.
> import_bookmarks (bool)      You may prevent the source document’s bookmarks 
>                              from being imported by specifying this as False.
> ```

This seems to be better suited to the taks you do then using the `PdfFileWriter`.

> ```
> from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
>
> # ...
>
> merger = PdfFileMerger()
>
> merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename1, 'rb')),None, [2])
> merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename2, 'rb')),None, [2])
>
> merger.write("document-output.pdf")
> ```

Example adapted from answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29871560/7505395

Comment: Your answer seems useful but I am having two problems. 1) The `file()` command doesn't work on my computer, but I fixed that with this 3 lines: `file = PdfFileReader(infile)`, `file.decrypt("")` and `merger.append(file, None, [2])`. 2) If the argument pages is `[2]` I got `TypeError: "pages" must be a tuple of (start, stop[, step])`, if the argument is some tuple range like e.g: `(0,2,1)` I got `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: file has not been decrypted`, **but** if the argument isn't it, "it works" -it append all the pages of the pdf... but at least it doesn't raise error-.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code at the following: https://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-split-a-pdf-every-2-pages-using-python/

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import glob
import sys

pdfs = glob.glob("*.pdf")

for pdf in pdfs:

    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(file(pdf, "rb"))

    for i in range(inputpdf.numPages // 2):

        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i * 2))

        if i * 2 + 1 <  inputpdf.numPages:
            output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i * 2 + 1))

        newname = pdf[:7] + "-" + str(i) + ".pdf"

        outputStream = file(newname, "wb")
        output.write(outputStream)
        outputStream.close()
```

Comment: I am sorry but your answer doesn't answer my question. You are spliting the pdf every two pages, I ask how to make a new pdf with only the **second** page of each pdf. I'm sorry.