# PyPDF2 PdfFileMerger.Merge Class

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to use this class to append a page from one PDF to another by specifying the page position.

Does anyone have experience with this? I couldn't find any example of using PdfFileMerger.merge over internet

```
with open(orig_pdf, 'rb') as orig, open(amend_pdf, 'rb') as new:

pdf = PdfFileMerger()
pdf.merge(2, new)
pdf.write('.pdf')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795091/how-to-append-pdf-pages-using-pypdf2?

Comment: Nahh dude, I want to specify the position

Comment: Please have a look at my code above

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `merge` and passing the `position`, which is the page number you wish to add the pdf file

There are (probably) many ways of achieving the same results. Heres a basic working example:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

orig_pdf = r'C:\temp\old.pdf'
amend_pdf = r'C:\temp\new.pdf'

with open(orig_pdf, 'rb') as orig, open(amend_pdf, 'rb') as new:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(orig_pdf))
    
    # Add amend_pdf after page 2
    merger.merge(2, PdfFileReader(amend_pdf))
    merger.write("results.pdf")
```

For more info, have a look at the official documentation https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html