# Getting string representation of pathlib object

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pathlib

I'm writing a python script to merge multiple PDFs into one to put into an output folder. Each PDF will be in a different folder with an employee name on it and it will need to be combined with the corresponding pdf in another folder. Not all employees will have each file so I included that in the logic.

The problem I am having currently is that PdfFileMerger expects a string when appending files and the pathlib library returns a windowpath object. That will not easily convert to a string. I'm getting this information about PyPDF2 from this post [pypdf Merging multiple pdf files into one pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104926/pypdf-merging-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf/17304537). I'm new to the pathlib library is there a conversion I should be doing or should I be getting a different path object?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from pathlib import Path

tc = Path('totalcomp')
merger = PdfFileMerger()


for i in tc.iterdir():
pdfs = []
try:
    pdfs.append(Path(f'profitshare/{i.name}'))
    pdfs.append(Path(f'merit/{i.name}'))
finally:
    pdfs.append(i)
    for pdf in pdfs:
        output = i.name
        merger.append(pdf, 'rb')
    merger.write(Path(f'/output/{i.name}'))
```

Answer (score 25):

According to [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)

> The string representation of a path is the raw filesystem path itself (in native form, e.g. with backslashes under Windows), which you can pass to any function taking a file path as a string:

```py
>>> p = PurePath('/etc')
>>> str(p)
'/etc'
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
>>> str(p)
'c:\\Program Files'
```

so the solution is to wrap `Path()` objects with `str()` function:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from pathlib import Path

tc = Path('totalcomp')
merger = PdfFileMerger()


for i in tc.iterdir():
pdfs = []
try:
    pdfs.append(str(Path(f'profitshare/{i.name}')))
    pdfs.append(str(Path(f'merit/{i.name}')))
finally:
    pdfs.append(i)
    for pdf in pdfs:
        output = i.name
        merger.append(pdf, 'rb')
    merger.write(str(Path(f'/output/{i.name}')))
```

BTW there is another one pathlib's method which returns a path as a string: [`as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix)

> Return a string representation of the path with forward slashes (/):

```py
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('c:\\windows')
>>> str(p)
'c:\\windows'
>>> p.as_posix()
'c:/windows'
```