# Merging all pdf files in a folder into one pdf with pypdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to merge all the PDFs in a directory with PyPDF2.

I tried the code from [pypdf Merging multiple pdf files into one pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104926/pypdf-merging-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for filename in os.listdir():
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(file(filename, 'rb')))

merger.write('Result.pdf')
```

I got an error!

```py
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Comment: I tried using `open` instead of `file`. That seems to solve the problem; however It does not close the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `with` block

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    with open(filename, 'rb') as source:
        tmp = PdfFileReader(source)
        merger.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @meTchaikovsky